# How can I find my memory leak with Leak Canary?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory-leaks

I implemented Leak Canary in my Android Studio project, ran the app in debug mode and rotated the screen (MainActivity) a couple of times to check for memory leaks. Leak Canary showed me the following screen:

[image]

The weird thing about this is, that I don't get this leak on a virtual device with API 27, but I get it on a virtual device with API 29 and on my real device. The next thing I want to mention, is, that I ran the Android Studio profiler on all of the devices. On the API 27 there was only 1 instance of MainActivity (and a couple of MainActivity$... classes, which I guess result from calls like `startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class))`).

On the other devices the number of instances increased with the number of device-rotations. When hitting the button **Force Garbage collection [FGC]** and looking at the dumped heap, the instances were still there, so this means there is a memory leak. **BUT** When hitting the **FGC** button again after a longer time and **then** looking at the dumped heap, the duplicate instances of the MainActivity were gone and there was only one instance left.

How can such a behavior occur?

Now, regarding my code:

**The PurchasesHandler class** contains the necessary code to handle Google Play purchases (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview). Since the whole class contains a lot of code, I will show the parts which contain a reference to the MainActivity or the class itself.

```
public class PurchasesHandler implements PurchasesUpdatedListener, AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener {
    private Activity activity;
    private BillingClient billingClient;
    private boolean adsRemoved;
    private ReviewedPurchasesCallback reviewedPurchasesCallback;


    public PurchasesHandler(Activity activity, boolean adsRemoved, ReviewedPurchasesCallback reviewedPurchasesCallback) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.adsRemoved = adsRemoved;
        this.reviewedPurchasesCallback = reviewedPurchasesCallback;
    }

    public interface ReviewedPurchasesCallback {
        void fun1();
        void fun2();
    }

    public void restorePurchases() {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this)
                .build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                    Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                    List<Purchase> purchaseList = purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
                    if (purchaseList != null && purchaseList.size() > 0) {
                        for (Purchase purchase : purchaseList) {
                                handlePurchase(purchase);
                        }
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                reviewedPurchasesCallback.fun1();
            }
        });

    }

    private void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (something...) {
            reviewedPurchasesCallback.fun2();
            if (purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                Log.i(...);
            } else {
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                        AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .build();
                billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, this);
            }
        } else if (something...) {
            reviewedPurchasesCallback.fun1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
        Log.i(...);
    }

    public void purchaseAdsRemoval() {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this)
                .build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                    ...
                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                            new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                                 List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                        SkuDetails skuDetail = skuDetailsList.get(0);
                                        if (sku.equals(something...)) {
                                            BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetail)
                                                    .build();
                                            billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams);
                                        }
                                }
                            });
                    ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                showBillingResponseDialog(...);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
            showBillingResponseDialog(...);
            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                handlePurchase(purchase);
            }
    }



    private void showBillingError(BillingResult billingResult) {
        switch (billingResult.getResponseCode()) {
            case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED:
                showBillingResponseDialog(0, resources.getString(...));
                break;
            ...
        }
    }

    private void showBillingResponseDialog(int titleCode, String message) {
        ...
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        ...
    }

    public void unregisterBillingListener() {
        if (billingClient != null) {
            billingClient.endConnection();
            billingClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity the class is implemented like this:

```
PurchasesHandler purchasesHandler = new PurchasesHandler(MainActivity.this, adsRemoved,
                                                new PurchasesHandler.ReviewedPurchasesCallback() {
            @Override
            public void adsRemovalNotPurchased() {
                loadConsentOrRetrieve();
            }

            @Override
            public void adsRemovalPurchased() {
                saveAdsRemovePref();
            }
        });
```

Do you think that the PurchasesHandler has something to do with the memory leak? And does someone know how to find the reason for the leak? Maybe a strategy or something?

### EDIT

Almost forgot the most important thing. In the MainActivity I also call:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        purchasesHandler.unregisterBillingListener();
        purchasesHandler = null;
    }
```

### EDIT 2

Through removing and adding code piece by piece and running the profiler every time, I found out that the listener is causing the problem.

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this)
```

It seems that this listener doesn't get suspended, when

```
billingClient.endConnection();
```

is called. Since I didn't find even 1 hint on the internet about this, I guess I have to live with this issue...